# azure container registry allow pull without login

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

We need to setup public docker repository, and trying to use azure container registry, but turns out you need to login to pull images from it, is there any way to avoid login for pull?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, ACR only offers private access.  You can host your own registry in Azure deploying [Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/).

Answer (score 0):

turns out they support it in preview mode, you should contact support to enable it.